# How to generate random numbers of type int16 using numpy.random.uniform?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

I'm trying to generate a numpy array of random int16 values, but the function `numpy.random.uniform` returns float64, so how to do that using this function or any similar function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [np.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) and specify the `dtype` parameter to be `np.int`, e.g.

```py
np.random.randint(0,10,5, dtype=np.int)
array([4, 4, 1, 1, 4], dtype=int)
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between `numpy.random.uniform` and `np.random.randint`?

Comment: `np.random.uniform` samples from continuous uniform distribution, while `np.random.randint` samples from a discrete uniform distribution.